# ¿Cómo puedo copiar las propiedades de un objeto que se encuentra dentro de otro?

Tags: javascript, vuex

Tengo un array de objetos ejemplo:

```
[{ 
 id: 123,
 name: 'test',
 description: 'this is a test product'
 cart: [
  {
   id: 124,
   price: 500,
   qty: 3
  },
  {
   id: 125,
   price: 500,
   qty: 3
  }
 ],
 image: '',
 subtotal: 'Aquí quiero poner la suma de los objetos hijos"
}];
```

Como podría recorrer ese array de objetos y el array de objetos que se encuentra interno para poder copiar la propiedades del objeto hijo pasarlas al objeto padre?

Este proceso lo hago en mi action de un module en vuex.

Edit:

Estoy intentando realizarlo de esta manera, no se si sea le mejor y la correcta de todas formas no me hace la operación.

```
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  const newObject = data[i]
  let total = 0

  for (let j = 0; j < newObject.cart.length; j++) {
    let op = newObject.cart[j]
    total += op.price * op.qty
  }

  data[i].subtotal = total
}
```

Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Hola, y ¿qué has intentado? Si lo has intentado, por favor sube el codigo e indica dónde tienes la dificultad. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras Hola! si, una disculpa, edité mi publicación con el código con el que estoy intentando realizarlo. Gracias

Comment: Hola, si has hallado una solución, lo correcto es escribirlo en el área de respuestas. Aunque ya has aceptado una respuesta como válida, eso no te impide el publicar tu propia respuesta. Te invito a leer [answer]. Cuando publiques tu respuesta, se espera que la misma contenga una explicación de la solución, no sólo que copies el código, de esa forma otros usuarios pueden entender cómo usar tu solución. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras Por si no te diste cuenta, en la respuesta que acepté como válida, hice un comentario diciendo que iba a editar el post y puse el código que use para solucionar mi problema (no solo copie y pegue, porque agregue más cosas a la solución que me brindaron, si la gente no lee ya no es mi problema. Saludos.

Comment: @AntonelliS Lo que te comenta Mauricio es correcto. Si has encontrado la solución y es diferente a la que te han propuesto deberías de ponerla como respuesta y explicar en que es diferente del resto. Las soluciones nunca van en el apartado de la pregunta (arriba). Si en tu caso la solución es la que te han propuesto pero cambiando algo mínimo podrías aclararlo en el comentario de la respuesta aceptada o proponer una edición en su respuesta. Por último, y como consejo, si la respuesta te sirvió que mínimo que votarla con un positivo en muestra de agradecimiento.

Comment: Las respuestas (aunque sea la tuya) debe ir en el campo de respuestas. Si es solo un pequeño retoque sobre la respuesta aceptada, mejor dejar un comentario y arreglar esa respuesta. Eso ayuda a encontrar la respuesta facilmente. Voy a editar tu pregunta sacando la respuesta de alli. Por favor, si es necesario, hace lo que te pedimos con la respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes probar con `forEach` para recorrer los arrays, en tu caso seria algo asi:

```js
let arr=[{ 
    id: 123,
    name: 'test',
    description: 'this is a test product',
    cart: [
     {
      id: 124,
      price: 500,
      qty: 3
     },
     {
      id: 125,
      price: 500,
      qty: 3
     }
    ],
    image: '',
    subtotal: 'Aquí quiero poner la suma de los objetos hijos'
}];

arr.forEach(e=>{
  let subTotal=0;
  e.cart.forEach(p=>{
    subTotal+=p.price*p.qty;
  })
  e.subtotal=subTotal;
});
console.log(arr[0].subtotal);
```

Espero que te sirva, saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias.. lo arreglé un poco pero ya está funcionando. Lo dejo arriba. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Una opción usando `map()` y `reduce()`:

```js
const arr = [{"id":123,"name":"test","description":"this is a test product","cart":[{"id":124,"price":500,"qty":3},{"id":125,"price":500,"qty":3}],"image":"","subtotal":3000}];

const res = arr.map(e => {
  e.subtotal = e.cart.reduce((p, c) => p + (c.price * c.qty), 0)
  return e;
});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me parece excelente esta respuesta, saludos!